# run time error (SIGSEGV) SPOJ Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, sieve-of-eratosthenes

Hi I'm getting SIGSEGV error for this problem, dont know where is th problem:   http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/ 
I tried to solve it by sieve-of-Eratosthenes algo given on Wikipedia.
here is my code, please help thanks in advance.

```
int main()
{
   int t;   // test cases

   cin>>t;

   while(t--)
   {
      long int m,n;
      cin>>m>>n;


      if( 1 <= m <= n <= 1000000000 && n-m<=100000)
      {
         bool a[n];
         for(long int i=2;i<=n;i++)
         {
            a[i]=true;  // set all to true
         }
         a[0]=false;
         a[1]=false;
         for( long int i=2;i*i<=n;i++)
         {
            if(a[i])
            {
               for( long int k=i*i;k<=n;k+=i)
               {
                  a[k]=false;
               }
            }
         }
         for(long int i=m;i<=n;i++)
         {
            if(a[i])
               cout<<i<<endl;         //Now all i such that a[i] is true are prime.
         }
         cout<<endl;
      }
      else
         return -1;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you ever consider formatting your code so that it would actually be readable ?

Comment: Did you try to compile with debugging symbols and use gdb?

Comment: `bool a[n];` <- You get a couple of relatively large `n`, and that will overflow the stack. Also, you're accessing the inexistent `a[n]`, and sieving from 2 to `n` is too slow for larger `n`.

Comment: What input are you giving it? I can run it successfully in ideone by replacing the cin statements and assigning the values in the code.

Comment: yes, its running successfully on ideone and my laptop, but on submission on SPOJ its giving the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There are 3401 primes below the square root of 10<sup>9</sup>](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PrimePi%5BSqrt%5B10%5E9%5D%5D). That's all you need to sieve any segment of numbers below the 10<sup>9</sup> upper limit.

So, first, sieve a segment from 2 to 31622. Store the resulting 3401 prime integers in an array.

Then for each pair of numbers `m <= n, m >= n - 100000` create a temporary array covering the segment from `m` to `n` inclusive, and sieve it with those primes you've calculated in the first step. You can stop each sieving when a prime's square is above a given `n`:

```
for( i=0; primes[i]*primes[i] <= n; ++i)
{
    ....
```

See also [my posts about the "offset sieve" of Eratosthenes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=offset+sieve+primes+user%3A849891).

Answer (score 4):

You have to use gdb to find out exactly what happened.  There are many things wrong with this code.

1. As pointed out in the comments, for n large enough your `a[n]` will overflow the stack.
2. You have an off-by-one error in your first and third `for` loops; you check `a[n]` but only allocated up to `a[n-1]`.  All of the `i <= n` should be `i < n`
3. `if( 1 <= m <= n <= 1000000000 && n-m<=100000)` is probably not what you intended; for any positive integer 'n', `(1 <= m <=n)` will be true

Comment: Good point about the comparison chains, but since `1 <= m`, `m <= n` and `n <= 1000000000` are promised by SPOJ, it does no harm in this case.

Comment: I tried to debug it by GDB, but it doesn't show any error.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been treated before on SO. For example, see [Sieve of Eratosthenes on Stack Overflow](http://www.programminglogic.com/the-sieve-of-eratosthenes-implemented-in-c/). You may also want to read this blog that describes a typical C implementation: [C implementation of Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://www.programminglogic.com/the-sieve-of-eratosthenes-implemented-in-c/). As pointed out above there are multiple issues with your code, so many in fact that you need to think about reorganizing it completely. Please read the linked posts to get ideas for how to do that successfully.